# Did anyone try the Under-The-Jack Pack backpack?

Tags: backpacks, reviews

Did anyone try the 
[Under-The-Jack Pack](https://www.betabrand.com/unisex-ultra-thin-laptop-backpack.html)? I am wondering how visible it is really? How comfortable? The only video review I could find doesn't even show the back of the guy wearing this ... thing.

Comment: Try to rephrase the question avoiding "did anyone do ...". Such questions are prototypically off topic on SE.

Comment: We said in chat this was a good question.

Comment: Wouldn't the visibility depend on what you stuff into it?

Comment: @GayotFow As much as I understand that it was asked in Chat first.  As it is phrased it should really stay in Chat.

Comment: You don't have to put the chat paragraph about in the body of your question. It's justification and unrelated to the question. It needs some edits, but at the moment you need to wait until everybody cools down and logic is restored.

Comment: Considered one of these instead? http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/scottevest-otg-jacket-holds-two-laptops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the visibility factor would be totally dependent on what sort of jacket you are wearing.  A loose fitting jacket would drape over it without revealing edges, a thin windbreaker or fitted suit would likely show the edges.

But from a travel point of view, it seems like it would not be comfortable when riding buses, subways, trains or planes, unless you remove your jacket and take off the backpack, at which point in time the concealment value is nil.

About the only real value in travel would be if you plan to go drinking with your laptop in tow in a seedy part of town.

That said, the thin form factor seems good simply because it keeps the pack from flopping around like a normal backpack with a laptop inside would.

Comment: Or you want to hide the bag from gate agents...

Comment: @chx - are you one of those that carries everything on board including the kitchen sink ;-)

Comment: The kitchen sink is screwed into the wall too solidly.

Comment: But fridge isn't...